# Expression list treated as compound expression

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to compile a program I got from the net. Trying to use  in codeblocks but its showing errors. I don't understand what is going wrong. I've looked up in various forums but not much light is shed. Can anyone help soon? Thanks in advance

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int print_num(int i, int j) { return i + j; }

int main() {
    std::function<int(int, int)> foo = print_num;
    std::function<int(int, int)> bar;

    try {
        std::cout << foo(10, 20) << '\n';
        std::cout << bar(10, 20) << '\n';
    } catch (std::bad_function_call& e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Bad function call\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are some of the errors other than 14 other errors saying declaration not done. I guess clearing these error would solve that problem.

> main.cpp|10|error: **'function' is not a member of 'std'**
>   main.cpp|10|error: **expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]**
>   main.cpp|10|error: **expected primary-expression before 'int'**

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11?

Comment: Always include the errors from the top.  Early errors often describe why later errors happen.  Include what your compiler is, and what compiler flags you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile with `-std=c++11` to add in the C++11 features.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cxx && ./a.out
30
ERROR: Bad function call
```

vs:

```
$ g++ test.cxx && ./a.out
test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cxx:10:3: error: ‘function’ is not a member of ‘std’
test.cxx:10:28: error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]
test.cxx:10:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
...
```